# Rails: Block particular Actions based on format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, routes, format

Based on several tutorials online, my rails app uses a :mobile format to render pages optimized for mobile devices.

So for some actions, I have a *.mobile.erb file, in addition to the *.html.erb file.

But what if I want to disallow certain actions on the mobile site?

For example, for a particular resource, you can do Index and Show, but not Edit or New, when you're mobile.

What's the best way to do this?  Currently, I just don't have edit.mobile.erb or new.mobile.erb, but that just shows a "Template Missing" error - not very graceful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try accessing params[:format] to check if the action is valid for a particular format. If not, you could redirect or show a custom error page, or whatever else it is you want to do to gracefully disallow an action.

```
#..inside your controller..

def do_something
  if !["html","xml"].include?(params[:format])
    #invalid format. do something
  end
  #..do other things
end
```

Comment: OK, I guess that's what I'll  do.  I was hoping for something graceful and rails-y, like some special keyword in Routes.rb.

I'll probably put in a before_filter in each controller that maps to a private method that does the whitelist/blacklist check.  Thanks for your suggestion!